# VS 2010 very slow

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, development-environment

I have just upgraded to VS 2010, and I have performance problems which I did not have before (in VS 2008).

The most annoying thing is that it freezes while I work in the text editor. Sometimes when it freezes I see that it is saving auto recovery information, but not always.

Almost anything I do gives an unacceptable long delay, like saving, starting to debug, ending debug session, switching between design and code view, and doing WinForms designing.

I have some parts of my home directory on a mapped network drive. I suspect that that might be a part of the problem. Is it possible to configure VS 2010 to use exclusively local disk for its "internal" work perhaps?

Any hints would be appreciated! Has anyone else experienced these kinds of problems?

Edit:
I forgot to give my specs:

- Win 7 64-bit
- 4 gb memory
- No addins, just standard installation
- The project folder is on the network drive

One interesting thing is that I feel that I have better performance in a VM running XP (where the VM runs on the same PC).

Comment: Which parts are on a network drive? Are the project directories on a network drive? Also, how much RAM do you have? Do you have any add-ins installed? Personally, I've found VS2010 actually feels a little *faster* than VS2008, which is pretty impressive given that it's a WPF app now!

Comment: Are you running under a VM? Some have a hard time with WPF

Comment: I too have found VS2010 faster than VS2008, but OK I don't have my stuff on a network drive.

Comment: I found VS2010 faster than VS2008, but working with quite complex WPF projects I have frequent freezes that last 10-30 seconds :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS is great if you do what microsoft recommends and work on a local copy of your projects.
As soon as you start tying to open projects in remote locations you will get this issue.

Recommendations:

1. use a source control solution.
2. create a copy of your project locally and run the solution from that.

Also ...

I think it does it's clever stuff in the background, I found the more i use it the faster it gets, especially on long running projects that I regularly go back to.

If you think it might be aformentioned WPF framework you may want to try switching off aero (as a test) if it helps the problem is likely that your chosen graphics hardware is not very good at effect or 3D based output so it's struggling.

Also try reducing the number of background services and apps you have running.

on windows 7 these days 4 gigs of ram is considered standard, so whilst it should perform fine maybe consider putting more ram in if you are trying to handle large datasets / similar business applications.

Another thing you could try is run a repair install over the top of your existing, it may not have cleanly installed something ... unlikely but it may help.

Comment: After I changed as many references to the networked drive to a local path instead, it runs much better!

Comment: Chances are the issue was network performance but if you think about the simple things you do (eg hitting F5 to compile and run) there's a lot of drive activity going on there. Hense the recommendation that you locally debug apps. 

Microsoft however do offer the remote debugger application that VS can connect to (not quite the same though is it).

Comment: *"VS is great if you do what microsoft recommends and work on a local copy of your projects*" - Yeah, except it's slow that way too.  It has been getting progressively worse with each new version.

Comment: Let me guess ... you use resharper? @EdS. ... I used to hate VS when I worked in a company where resharper was mandatory, since moving on I have found VS to be great even the 2015 version

Answer (score 2):

If you can, buy an SSD disk and move all your projects locally.
I find VS2010 super intensive on disk.
It fly on my home machine with an SSD but it's almost unusable on my work machine(Win7 4 gig RAM, but standard disk)

Comment: Same here, SSD (and 8gb RAM) at home, no problems. 4gb RAM at work and clunky disk, major performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the number of parallel builds to half the number of cores you have (I think its in options, settings, Solutions and Project, build and run).. I had it set to 8 which was too much.. it spawned 8 msbuild.exe, rebuilding a solution with 70 projects bottlenecked the disk  when they all tried to read/writte similar pre-compiled headers. Those msbuild's stick around even after you close the IDE.

Also I disabled the gather browsing info for implicit files, which made intellisense parsing quicker.

Answer (score 0):

An old post I know, but in case it helps others (as the previous answers focused on source code)...

I found that it wasn't my source code that was the issue, that was held locally along with all the references, but the default locations (project, project templates and item templates) as these were held on a networked drive. These can be altered in the `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions`.

Alternatively you could change the frequency of the saves or turn them off altogether via `Tools -> Options -> AutoRecover`