# Visual Studio 2010 - How to optimize

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, delay

I am using the 2010 version of Visual Studio, but am having many problems with delays - my computer has a good configuration of RAM, and processor - especially when saving files.

Currently I am carrying a medium-sized project, only one open file (ASP.NET page) using a single suite of components from third party, the Telerik. And yet, in time to save, or modify the tab, the entire IDE is slow. I know there may be several factors for this problem, but I'm not carrying the computer (the problem apparently is the memory management on behalf of the IDE).

Does anyone know any way to improve it? Change settings, Windows services. Oh yes, I'm using a plugin to modify the color of the IDE and another to find (Ctrl-click) the object reference.

Memory Initialization:

- Memory: 280000K
- Virtual Memory: 350000K

Comment: Did you defrag your disk before you installed it?  Run Fraggler to find out how bad it is.

Comment: I removed the plugin that was used to fetch the references of each object (CTRL + click) and the IDE was better (performance).

Comment: This tip applies to all Windows. It's always good to do that with computers, speeds up enough. And answering your question, I did not realize the defrag before install it. Thansk Hans Passant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you tried disabling all the plugins and make sure that it is VS that actually causes the slowdown?**

I have Resharper installed and VS can be slow sometimes. I turned it off (suspend on v5), and VS is back to blazing speed. Of course, inversely coding productivity is impaired by not having Resharper.

Comment: Friend, I had several plugins. I realized I started to get slow. Then removed them, and leave only those two, which are lightweight and necessary. Also, Visual Studio is slow to close up. Practically, let all my SO slow. @Adrian Godong

Comment: Turn off those two, and see if it's slow. If it is, you may need an updated graphic card driver or a new card altogether (VS2010 runs on WPF). If it's not slow, then the plugin is the culprit. Contact the plugin developer to improve the performance.

Comment: The IDE interface and 2010 are very good. However, I was very sad when I found out (release) it was developed in WPF. Visual technology and good, but is still slow. Uninstall the applications but still the same.

Comment: That means you may need to update the graphic driver or upgrade the graphic card. What card are you using right now?

Comment: Intel(R) Q33 Express Chipset Family/ Display Memory: 384.0 MB /     Current Mode: 1440 x 900 (32 bit) (75Hz) - I believe that this is not the problem because I do not see anything so heavy on him, despite being done in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

There are many causes and circumstances that can lead to what you're describing. So I'd better recommend you to check the links bellow...

[VS.Net 2010 IDE Very Slow](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vs2010ctpeditor/thread/cfcc5c16-81ad-4469-8b16-f24669072f0f)

[VS 2010 very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880034/vs-2010-very-slow)

[VS 2010 slow for edit of first file in project with many web references](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/69a3eda6-f71f-42ac-93ee-5cc2b0980a1c)

[VS2010 C#: Delay when opening a file inside IDE](https://superuser.com/questions/128753/vs2010-c-delay-when-opening-a-file-inside-ide)

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 was more limited, but was faster. I read the links, but do not believe that is network problem. Working with the project site, and use the TFS 2010. - Primeiro brasileiro que eu encontro aqui. Como é bom, escrever em português @Leniel Macaferi

Comment: Se escrevermos em Português aqui, só nós entenderemos. :)