# Visual Studio 2010 No Responding and Layout Error in WIN7 X64

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have encounted a serious problem after installation VS 2010.
Every time, starting the VS2010 is very slow and frequently no responding.
When working in the VS2010, every action, such as clicking the menu button or dragging the toolbox or solution explorer, the layout will have errors like below picture.
Even building the simpliest program, it's very slow and always meet part of black screen.
I don't think it's due to my computer, because my laptop has an i5 CPU and 6G RAM and GT540M video card.
Besides, I have tried ultimate and professioal version many times, but the issue is not fixed. And SP1 patched has been installed alrealy.

Really appreciate your help!

PS, because my low reputation, I cannot attach the picture, please refer to the picture in my photo blog here：[Visual Studio 2010 Issue](http://my.poco.cn/album/album_show_photo_list.htx&user_id=55984787&set_hash=2919802671)

Comment: Have you installed any 3rd party tools like Re-Sharper or AnkhSVN etc? There have been cases, where people have faced these issues, because of the plugins taking lot of memory.

Comment: @PawanMishra According to your suggestion, I have uninstalled the VM Ware. And Use the devenv /ResetSettings and devenv /ResetSkipPkgs in Command prompt, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the images, I can see that the rendering of VS is very slow. Try the following step :

- Go to tools and select Options
- Under Environment category, choose "General" and then on right side, uncheck the "Automatically adjust the visual experience based on client performance"

The problem you are facing is pretty generic and its hard to pin-point as whats going wrong. Following are some helpful links :

http://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/24/does-your-visual-studio-run-slow/ (this is meant for VS 2008, not sure how much it is applicable for VS 2010)

[VS 2010 very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880034/vs-2010-very-slow)